# Using list comprehension with for loops and multiple if statements

Tags: python

I've been browsing several posts about `for` loops and `if` statements in a list comprehension but can't wrap my head around how to implement it.

I'm reading in a text file with several "reviews" but for this example's purpose and without making this too long of an example, say `file` is:

```
product/productId: B001E4KFG0
review/userId: A3SGXH7AUHU8GW
review/profileName: delmartian
review/helpfulness: 1/1
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1303862400
review/summary: Good Quality Dog Food
review/text: I have bought several things.
```

This code works though not the most succinct or efficient. I'm trying to get each block (`Product_ID` and `Rating`) into their own list comprehension. I'm sure there are even better ways to do that but that is well beyond my skill set.

```
for line in file:

    # `Product_ID`
    if 'product/productId' in line:
            line_list = line.split(':')
            Product_ID = line_list[1].strip()
            line_count += 1

    # `Rating`
    if 'review/score' in line:
            line_list = line.split(':')
            Rating = line_list[1].strip()
            line_count += 1
```

I think I have the `line_list` part in the list comprehension but don't see how to get the `Product_ID` (or `Rating`) assignment in the same statement.

```
# Where does Product_ID = line_list[1].strip() go?
Product_ID = [line.split(':') for line in file if 'product/productId' in line]

# Where does Rating = line_list[1].strip() go?
Rating = [line.split(':') for line in file if 'review/score' in line]
```

Want returned:

```
Product_ID = ['B001E4KFG0']
Rating = ['5.0']
```

Comment: If you are building two or more lists, I would prefer a single loop over multiple list comprehensions, so that you aren't duplicating the iteration.

Comment: Note that after the first comprehension, the file iterator is exhausted; the second one won't see any data unless you use `file.seek(0)` to "reset" the iterator first.

Comment: Ah, so perhaps this isn't even an appropriate scenario for list comprehension. I thought it might be and was trying to put together some skills I (kinda) know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very close to your solution.

```
# Where does Product_ID = line_list[1].strip() go?
Product_ID = [line.split(':') for line in file if 'product/productId' in line]
```

This will return a list of two elements, split by the ':'. You simply want the second element in the list

```
# Where does Product_ID = line_list[1].strip() go?
Product_ID = [line.split(':')[1] for line in file if 'product/productId' in line]
```

You may also want to strip the preceeding blank space using

```
# Where does Product_ID = line_list[1].strip() go?
Product_ID = [line.split(':')[1].strip(' ') for line in file if 'product/productId' in line]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add them right after the split, you keep operating on this object

```
Product_ID = [line.split(':')[1].strip() for line in file if 'product/productId' in line]

Rating = [line.split(':')[1].strip() for line in file if 'review/score' in line]
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is good for building *a* list. In your case, you are building multiple lists, so a `for` loop that updates one of several lists on each iteration is more appropriate. Something like

```
product_ids = []
ratings = []

for line in file:
    key, value = line.split(":")
    if key == 'product/productId':
        lst = product_ids    
        value = value.strip()
    elif key == 'review/score':
        lst = ratings
        value = value.strip()
    else:
        # No interesting data on this line
        continue

    lst.append(value)
    line_count += 1
```

If `line_count` is meant to include lines whether or not they update a list, move it before the `if` statement, or simply use enumerate to get the final line count:

```
for line_count, line in enumerate(file):
```